# Add a list or multiple choice item after a page break

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written as script that creates multiple page breaks in a Google Form. But I cant figure out how to programmatically add a multiple choice question to one of the page breaks.

For example.

**Page 1(Main page)**

**Page 2**

Multiple choice question here

**Page 3**

List element here

How would I add those form elements in app script to a specific page break?

Comment: In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample of `Multiple choice question` you expect as an image? And also, can you provide your current script?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: This solution from Tanaike would seem to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54985298/add-a-google-form-question-to-a-specific-section-of-a-form-using-google-apps-scr